# meteor not printing any data

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have the following application and when I render data I am getting null or no data for the `{{video}}` tag even though data exists in the collection  Can anyone help me find the mistake

> routes.js

```
Router.route('/videos/:id', function () {
  var item = Videos.find({_id: this.params._id});
  this.render('VideoItem', { data:item});
});
```

> video.html

```
<template name="VideoItem">
  <div class="container">
    <h3> Video Information</h3>
    {{video}} 
  </div>
</template>
```

> video object when  Videos.find().fetch()

```
_id: "FEXm65hwZ9QWXFSY8"
created_at: Mon May 18 2015 14:22:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)
duration: 10000
video: "temp"
videourl: "http://google.com"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns a cursor. That would work if you were iterating over a set of videos with `#each`. In your case you want a specific video so you'd need to use `findOne` like this:

```
Router.route('/videos/:_id', function () {
  this.render('VideoItem', {
    data: function () {
      return Videos.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed it to findone but still the video prints nothing :(

Comment: can you `console.log(item);` right before the `this.render`? I just want to make sure it's actually published.

Comment: its undefined but on the browser console if I do a fetch I can access the data... how is that possible? Sorry I am a meteor noob here

Comment: Replace the route with my updated answer which uses a function for `data`. If that works I'll explain what's happening.

Comment: that worked there is a typo (no flower brace) .. can you please explain the answer :) thank you very much

Comment: Cool. Okay so what's happening is `data` is a reactive computation so whenever `Videos.findOne` changes, so will your context. In your original code, the video was only being fetched once before the route ran. If the video wasn't published (or hadn't yet arrived on the client) it would never be sent to the template.